# Can't export action creator to component mapDispatchToProps method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-thunk

In my action file I create a fetchMethod

```
export const requestEmbedToken = () => (dispatch) => {

    return axios.get('http://localhost:7071/api/getTokens')
        .then(response => {
            console.log("token embed", response)

        })
}
```

app.js

import { requestEmbedToken } from './redux/actions'

```
function App(token, requestToken) {
  const [embedToken, setEmbedToken] = useState(token.token);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (token.token === undefined) {
      requestToken()
      setEmbedToken(token.token)
    }
  });
  return (

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return ({
    requestToken: () => dispatch(requestEmbedToken())
  })
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

Actually I'm getting an error

> TypeError: requestToken is not a function

Comment: i think it should be ```props.requestToken()``` and I'm not sure you have to wrap the return of the ```mapDispatchToProps``` in parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

`App` component will receive all the props as properties of an object that will be passed as an argument, commonly referred to as `props` object. You need to destructure the `props` object to access the token and other props

```
function App({ token, requestToken }) {
  ...
}
```

Alternatively, you could use the `props` object instead of destructuring it

```
function App(props) {
  ...
}
```

and then use `props.token` and `props.requestToken` to access the props as properties of `props` object.